Querying all users who follow all the users a certain user follows in SQLite
Intro:
I've been learning SQLite and have had trouble coming up with a satisfactory solution to this query prompt. My strategy involves calculating the complement of users following everyone John Doe follows. However, it is messy and I can't help thinking there must be a cleaner and more simple solution.
Relevant Tables:
Follows(flwer, flwee, date)
Users(usr, name)
where flwer, flwee, and usr are all int user ids and keys
Prompt:

Find the id of users who follow every user followed by John Doe. The match for John Doe should be case-insensitive.

My Solution:
Select flwer from
(
Select * from follows
Except
Select *
From follows f2
Where not exists (
    Select flwer, flwee
    From follows, users u1
    Where flwee = f2.flwee and flwer = u1.usr and upper(u1.name) = upper("John Doe")
    ) 
)
group by flwer having count(*) >= (Select Count(*) From follows, users u1 where flwer = u1.usr and upper(u1.name) = upper("John Doe"))

Any guiding advice on this? In set notation I want all x s.t {x following} is a super sets of {John Doe following}

Would a follower's list of followees have to have exactly match John Doe's list of Followees? Like if John Doe was following ids 1,2,5,6,8 would the output only include users that also follow that EXACT same list, or would a follower of just user 1 be included in your final output?

@JNevill No, its just has to be a super set. That is: Everyone John Doe follows exist with in the other persons following list, but the other person may follow additional people

You could consider using the Count() Window Function to get the count of a follower's followees for your John Doe count compare. This is similar to the direction you are taking in your SQL.
I'm also encapsulating some of the reusable logic in a CTE to keep the code clean:
WITH JohnDoe AS (
    SELECT flwee
    FROM Follows
    WHERE flwer = (SELECT usr FROM Users WHERE name = 'John Doe')
)
SELECT DISTINCT Users.Name
FROM (
      SELECT flwer, flwee, COUNT(flwee) OVER (PARTITION BY flwer) as flwee_count
      FROM Follows
      WHERE flwee IN (SELECT flwee FROM JohnDoe)
    ) as sub 
  INNER JOIN Users 
     ON sub.flwer = Users.usr
WHERE flwee_count >= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM JohnDoe);

dbfiddle of this in action here
